# New API Controller Not Being Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

We have a new .NET 4.7.1 API with one controller that is already working. However, when adding a second controller we receive 404s when trying to access the method on the new controller

Working, existing controller accessed using **http://localhost/OurAPI/api/v1/UserInfo/GetUserInfo**:

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/v1/UserInfo")]
    public class UserInformationController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetUserInfo", Name = "GetUserInfo")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetUserInfo()
        {
             return Ok("Old Controller");
        }
    }
```

Broken, New Controller accessed using **http://localhost/OurAPI/api/v1/Test/TestStuff** :

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/v1/Test")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult TestStuff()
        {
                return Ok("Test");
        }
    }
```

My route config:

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

I'm stumped as to why this is happening, I've created many controllers in different APIs and have not encountered an issue like this.

UPDATE:

I read through all the replies, thanks to everyone for helping me come to figure this out!

In my attempt to shrink down / hide the code displayed on my initial question, I accidentally did some bad copy and pasting that probably mislead everyone reading it.

My **actual** new controller code:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

    [RoutePrefix("api/v1/Test")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult TestStuff()
        {
                return Ok("Test");
        }
    }
```

My issue here is that this project is a **web API**, not an **MVC** project. I was using System.Web.Mvc attributes and types when I should have been using System.Web.Http.

My working new controller code:

```
using System.Web.Http;
    [RoutePrefix("api/v1/Test")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("SetPassword")]
        public IHttpActionResult Test()
        {
            return Ok("test");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have not specified a route in the new controller.  You can either drop the TestStuff from the URI or add the route("TestStuff") to the code.

Comment: Where does the `/OurAPI` part of your route get configured? I cannot see how the first route works.

Comment: @DavidG I believe that comes from the project URL that is set in our project's properties to be "http://localhost/OurAPI"

Answer (score 2):

It appears you just forgot to add an attribute for the route. This should solve your problem. Note: The "Name" portion is optional, but since you have it on the other endpoint, I chose to put it here as well.

```cs
[Route("TestStuff", Name = "TestStuff")]
```

I want to point out however that your routing configuration sets up conventional routing, but then you are using attribute routing. I would generally recommend choosing one or the other.

.NET Framework WebApi2 docs on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/
.NET Core MVC docs on same subject: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: They are showing the wrong configuration. That is for MVC routes, web api routes would be in `WebApiConfig` class by default.